# Applying KVL in circuits containing inductors

Tags: electric-circuits, inductance

I have a question that is exactly the same as [this one](http://physicstasks.eu/1538/conducting-rails),

> Two long, parallel and perfectly conducting rails at a distance 50 cm from each other are placed in a homogeneous magnetic field with magnetic induction 2 mT, which is perpendicular to the rail plane. The rails are conductively connected at one point. Electrical resistance of the connection is 5 Ω. A perfectly conducting rod slides on these rails with a constant speed 2 ms-1. Determine:
>
> a) electromotive force induced in the conducting rod, the value and direction of induced electric current in the closed part of the circuit,
>
> b) mechanical pulling force needed to keep the rod at the constant speed and mechanical power.
>
> [image]

except that in my case there is a coil of inductance $L$ in place of the $R$. Following are my questions:

1. Do we have to take $di/dt$ positive for the coil? I think it should because induced current will be there in the circuit due to change in flux but I am not sure.
2. After some time will the induced current  will be constant?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).